# Entity Framework 5 Code First Self-Referencing Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-5

How would I map the following relationship in Entity Framework 5?

```
public class Item {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int? ParentItemId { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }

  public Item ParentItem { get; set; }
  public List<Item> ChildItems { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

  modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
              .HasOptional(i => i.ParentItem)
              .WithMany(i => i.ChildItems)
              .HasForeignKey(i => i.ParentItemId);
}
```

and this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

  modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
              .HasMany(i => i.ChildItems)
              .WithOptional(i => i.ParentItem)
              .HasForeignKey(i => i.ParentItemId);
}
```

which both result in this error:

**The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role.**

If I start with database-first mapping, here is what the generated entity looks like:

```
public partial class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        this.ChildItems = new HashSet<Item>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentItemId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> ChildItems { get; set; }
    public virtual Item ParentItem { get; set; }
}
```

I know this will work if I start with db-first, I just need to know how to define the relationship in code-first.

Comment: Is `Id` the key property? Or do you have a key mapping (with Fluent API?) to another property, for example to `Value`?

Comment: Id is the primary key property of Item.

Comment: "*types of all properties in the Dependent Role*" means the types of the FK property which is `ParentItemId` and has type `int?`. "*corresponding property types in the Principal Role*" means the types of the PK property which is `Id` and has type `int`. They are the same (nullability doesn't matter). However, the exception says, they are not. The exception would occur if you had for example a `long` (or any other type) for the PK and an `int?` for the FK. Rather strange...

Comment: I have copied the code you posted and run it, and it runs without errors on my system. I can create and read Items, no exception thrown. I am using VS2013 RC and EF 6

Comment: @Slauma That was the issue. I posted a simplified representation of the problem here (since the real entities are huge), but the primary key of Item was actually marked as long. Thanks for pointing that out. Please post a response and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception means the following:

- "*types of all properties in the Dependent Role*" are the types of the FK property which is `ParentItemId` and has type `int?` in your model
- "*corresponding property types in the Principal Role*" are the types of the PK property which is `Id` and has type `int` in your model

They are the same (nullability doesn't matter). However, the exception says, they are not.

The exception normally would only occur if the types don't match, for example if you had a `long` (or any other type) for the PK and an `int?` for the FK.

Answer (score 9):

**In code first change your entity class like this:**

```
   public class Item 
   {
      public Item()
      {
            this.ChildItems = new HashSet<Item>();
      }

      public int Id { get; set; }
      public Nullable<int> ParentItemId { get; set; }
      public string Value { get; set; }

      public virtual Item ParentItem { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Item> ChildItems { get; set; }
  }
```

**Write the following code to your context file:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                    .HasOptional(i => i.ParentItem)
                    .WithMany(i => i.ChildItems)
                    .HasForeignKey(i => i.ParentItemId);
    }
```

Think this should work.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. When attempting it this way, I still get the same error:

The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role.

Answer (score 4):

Why not try this:

```
 public class Item 
   {
      public Item()
      {
            ChildItems = new HashSet<Item>();
      }

      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int? ParentItemId { get; set; }
      public string Value { get; set; }

      public virtual Item ParentItem { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Item> ChildItems { get; set; }
  }
```

And in your DataContex Class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                    .HasOptional(i => i.ParentItem)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(i => i.ParentItemId);
    }
```

Hope this work.

Also there is a good article here:
**How to Configure a Self Referencing Entity in Code First**
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2011/06/03/how-to-configure-a-self-referencing-entity-in-code-first/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the mapKey way of doing it rather than using HasForeignKey. Like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.Department)
    .WithMany(t => t.Courses)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("ChangedDepartmentID"));
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. When trying it this way, I get the following error: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'ParentItemId' was already defined.

Comment: Add an ignore to the ParentItemId property right before the above many to one mapping..

modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().Ignore(it => it.ParentItemId );